Find the minimum value of $E = (x - y)(y-z)(z-u)(u-x)$ if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2 = 1$.

The sum of the squares of four reals $x, y, z, u$ is $1$. Find the minimum value of the expression $E = (x - y)(y-z)(z-u)(u-x)$. Find also the values of $x, y, z$ and $u$ when this minimum occurs.

I tried applying AM $\ge$ GM but that way I was getting the maximum value of $E$ as $0$. So, I tried using GM $\ge$ HM but that didn't help either.
I tried using Cauchy-Schwartz too
\begin{align}
&(x^2  +y^2 + z^2 + u^2 ) (1 + 1 + 1+ 1) \ge (x+y+z+u)^2
\\\implies\:& 4 \ge ( x+y+z+u)^2
\\\implies\:& x+y+z+u  \le 2
\end{align}
So, minimum value of $E$ should be $0$ when $ x=y=z=u=1/2$. But, this was the maximum value according to $AM \ge GM $
What am I doing wrong ? How should I proceed ?
Edit: I just realized that I can't use AM $\ge$ GM here as $x,y,z,u$ are not given positive. But even after using Cauchy the proof is incomplete. So, what should be the correct solution ?

If $y>z>u>x$ then $E$ is negative, no?

Oh right, zero isn't the minimum. So, how do I find the minimum value ?

Can you find an upper bound for $(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-u)^2(u-x)^2$?

@JyrkiLahtonen Not quite sure that would work. Say that the expression lies in $[-0.5, 1]$, then an upper bound for the square is 1, but doesn't tell you about the minimum.

You can see the comment on my third answer for this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464810/when-a2-b2-c2-d2-1-and-the-expression-a-bb-cc-dd-a/4908911#4908911

The duplicate question suggests that an optimal solution (there are eight similar solutions) is $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{4} \approx 0.683$, $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{4} \approx 0.183$, $z=\frac{-\sqrt{3}+1}{4} \approx -0.183$, and  $u=\frac{-\sqrt{3}-1}{4} \approx -0.683$, giving minimal $E=-\frac18=-0.125$.

True @CalvinLin. At that time I was just tossing an idea on the table. That idea probably should stay there.

$(x-y)(y-z)(z-u)(u-x)$
$=(x-y)(z-u)(y-z)(u-x)$
$=(xz + yu - xu - yz)(yu + zx -xy - zu)$
This can be expressed as matrix notation
$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
xz & yu & -xu & -yz
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
xz \\ 
yu \\ 
-xy \\
-zu
\end{array}\right)$
This can be reduced to
$=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
xz & yu & -xu & -yz
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
xz \\ 
yu \\ 
-xy \\
-zu
\end{array}\right)$
Note that the order of elements can be swapped
$=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
xu & yz & -zx & -yu
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
xy \\ 
-yu \\ 
-xz \\
zu
\end{array}\right)$
$=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
u \\ z \\ -x \\ -y
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u \\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
y \\ 
-u \\ 
-x \\
z
\end{array}\right)$
This can be rewritten as weighted norm of vectors
$=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x \\ y \\ z \\ u
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u \\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\
u
\end{array}\right)$
The weight matrices above are rotation matrices in 4D space, because $A^TA=I$ and $\det (A)=1$
Therefore, the question you suggested can be viewed as finding least value of the product of weighted norms with the given matrices
Luckily, the rotation axis of the given matrices are the same
The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the  first matrix is
$\lambda = 1, -1, i, -i, \;
\Lambda=
\frac{1}{2}
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & -i & i \\
-1 & -1 & -i & i \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$
And for the second one,
$\lambda = 1, -1, i, -i, \;
\Lambda=
\frac{1}{2}
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & i & -i \\
-1 & 1 & i & -i \\
-1 & -1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$
The basis can be changed to standard basis
Then, the transform becomes
$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u \\
\end{array}\right)
\rightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & -y & -u & z \\
\end{array}\right)
$
$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u \\
\end{array}\right)
\rightarrow
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & -u & -z & y \\
\end{array}\right)
$
Therefore,
$\min \; (x-y)(y-z)(z-u)(u-x)$
$=\min \;
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u \\
\end{array}\right) 
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x \\ -y \\ -u \\ z
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & u \\
\end{array}\right) 
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x \\ -u \\ -z \\ y
\end{array}\right)
$
$= \min \; (x^2-y^2)(x^2-z^2)$
when $x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2=1$
Parametrizing the variables with hyperspherical coordinate to utilize the symmetry
$u = \cos \alpha, \; x = \sin \alpha \cos \beta, \; y = \sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma, \; z = \sin \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma,$
where $0 \leq \alpha , \; \beta \leq \pi, \; 0 \leq \gamma \leq 2 \pi$
Then,
$(x^2-y^2)(x^2-z^2)$
$ = ((\sin \alpha \cos \beta)^2-(\sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma)^2)((\sin \alpha \cos \beta)^2-(\sin \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma)^2)$
$ = \sin^4 \alpha (\cos^4 \beta - \sin^2 \beta \cos^2 \beta + \sin^4 \beta \cos^2 \gamma \sin^2 \gamma)$
substitution for simplicity, $0 \leq A \leq 1, \; 0 \leq C \leq \frac{1}{4}$
$ = A (\cos^4 \beta - \sin^2 \beta \cos^2 \beta + C \sin^4 \beta)$
$ = A ((2 + C) \sin^4 \beta - 3 \sin^2 \beta + 1)$
$ = A ((2 + C) (\sin^2 \beta - \frac{3}{2(C+2)})^2 + 1 - \frac{9}{4(C+2)})$
Since $\frac{2}{3} \leq \frac{3}{2(C+2)} \leq \frac{3}{4}$, this has minimum $A(1 - \frac{9}{4(C+2)})$ at $\sin^2 \beta = \frac{3}{2(C+2)}$
From $-\frac{1}{8} \leq 1 - \frac{9}{4(C+2)} \leq 0$ and $0 \leq A \leq 1$,
The global minimum becomes $-\frac{1}{8}$

Your statement believes that $x/y=z/u$, but that's not required in the question.

Nor is it fulfilled by the $x,y,z,u$ you found. A correct start should use hyperspherical polar coordinates that involves three angles, not two.

You guys are correct. I will think about it for day and If I can't solve it, I will delete my statement. Thank you.

@KurtG. As you pointed, I introduced hyperspherical coordinate.
